# Specifying initial database version when using SQLDelight

Tags: android, sqldelight

We're migrating from the Android platform `SQLiteDatabase`/`SQLiteOpenHelper` to use SQLDelight. Our first public database version was `17`. By default, the SQLDelight `Schema` returns `1` for `version`. The only way I've been able to find to force `version` to `17` is to provide an empty `16.sqm` migration file. Is this the correct way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: I am also looking for an answer i am not eben able to alter the table in .sqm file. How you did that?

Comment: Pretty sure this approach of adding an empty file with the initial version number is the way to go. We did the same thing when trying to migrate from GreenDao to SQLDelight and that works like a charm.